# Can Java use String as an index array key? (ex: array["a"]=1;)

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

Can Java use a String as an index array key? Example:

```
array["a"] = 1;
```

Comment: what about multidimensional array like array["a"]["b"]?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

No.

To do something like this, you have to use a Map.

```
Map<String, Integer> aMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
aMap.put("a" , Integer.valueOf(1));
```

Comment: +1, But couldn't you use `Integer.valueOf(1)` since a new `Integer` instance isn't really required? Actually, you could just use the constant `1` instead of needlessly wrapping, right?

Comment: @mre the only advantage with not using the constant is that it'll work with versions before 1.5 when autoboxing was introduced. For all modern versions though I agree the constant would be better!

Answer (score 42):

No - you want a map to do that:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("a", 2);
```

Then to get it:

```
int val = map.get("a"); //2
```

You can only use the square bracket syntax for arrays, not for any of the collections. So something like:

```
int val = map["a"]; //Compile error
```

Will always be illegal. You have to use the `get()` method.

Answer (score 15):

No, that would be a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) in Java.

(The type would be `Map<String,Integer>`.)

Answer (score 6):

No they can't. But they can use chars the ASCII value of the alphabet will be used as the key index

Consider

```
    String[] a = new String['a' + 1];
    a['a'] = "Hello";
    int[] b = new int['a' + 3];
    b['c'] = 5;

    System.out.println(a[97]);
    System.out.print(b[99]);
```

This will output

```
Hello
5
```

Comment: Your arrays is of size 98 to store two values, also 99 (for 'c') is out of range.

Comment: The arrays are indeed large for something so simple, however, the question is about whether Java can use a String as an index array key not about how efficient it is. Also, the ascii code for 'a' is 97, add 3 to that and you arrive at 100 for the size of array b. Since the ascii code for 'c' is 99, you can access the value at the 99th index of the array without throwing any ````IndexOutOfBoundsException````s. If you have no more reservations, please undo your downvote, so that this answer can be useful to other readers, even if just from a purely educational standpoint

Comment: Such operations are actually used in algorithms like R-way Tries where the Radix is the total number of ASCII characters available, so it's not entirely uncommon or inefficient to work with arrays this way

Comment: @cyroxis, could you please remove your downvote because it's misleading for other readers who come to this page

Comment: you make some good points. I can not change my vote unless the answer is edited.

Comment: Done. I made a small edit to reactivate the answer. I wouldn't mind an upvote if you don't mind, just to bring some attention to the right answer for this question

Comment: while a workaround is technically a solution, this one is a really, really, really bad suggestion in 9,999 cases out of 10,000.   i recommend that you post a serious disclaimer or you will keep on being downvoted.  note: i personally did NOT downvote you.  but i came THIS close.

Comment: On the contrary @tonygil, my answer isn't suggesting a workaround for anything. The question is simply "Can Java use a String as an index array key?" and the answer that it can at least use character based keys, which would seem to be sufficient given that the proposed string keys in the example contain a single character each

Comment: On a different note, i was made aware of this question by a college student who used a map to implement an English language dictionary data structure for a school project after reading the answers here, when a Trie with character keys would have been the most effective way to go about doing what he wanted.

This method is used extensively to implement dictionaries, spell checkers and a few other extended ASCII based data structures and programs

Comment: Just wanted to point out: the OP wanted to know if arrays can have a String as index, not a character.