# 2D array in Java using characters including special characters as index

Tags: java

Is it possible to create a 2d array in java, such the column and row names are letter-characters and we can access like `array[E][*] = ...` ?

Here we can't use map because Map corresponds to 1-D array. So what will be the other alternatives ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Create an array with letter characters as index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069609/java-create-an-array-with-letter-characters-as-index)

Comment: You can use a 26 X 26 array and index it using the value `(letter - 'a')` if it is a lowercase letter, and `(letter -'A')` if it is an uppercase letter.

Comment: I need to use special characters too.

Answer (score 0):

As you said in the comments that Map corresponds to 1D array, why not use Map of Maps.

```
Map<Character,Map<Character,Character>> outerMap = new HashMap<Character, Map<Character, Character>>();
```

and use a simple method to fetch your data:

```
public char getValue(char row ,char column, Map<Character,Map<Character,Character>> outerMap) {

return  outerMap.get(row).get(column);

}
```

Good Luck!