# Question in regards to a line of the code

Tags: java, arrays

In the below code snipped I have a  question, the given declared array is of type integer.Can you please explain on what is happening at the line map[s.charAt(i)]++. I am having trouble understanding the statement here as the array is of type integer during initialization, but character type are being given as input.

```
public int firstUniqChar(String s) 
{ 
int[] map = new int[128]; 
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
 map[s.charAt(i)]++; 
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) 
if(map[s.charAt(i)] == 1) 
return i; 
return -1;
 }
```

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11069635/11301900

Comment: Yes it does. Thank  you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In java, supposing you have a `int i = 0` variable declaration, the `i++` is a syntax suggar to sum 1 to variable value, i.e. `i = i + 1`.
In your case you are summing 1 to an `map` array position, indexed by `s.charAt(i)`.

Supposing `s` is a String object, `s.charAt(i)` returns the `char` at the `i` position (0-indexed). When the Java reads the `char` as a `int` (to index the `map` array), is uses the ASCII code of that `char`.

So, what `map[s.charAt(i)]++` does is to sum 1 to the `map` array indexed by the charactere's ASCII code.