# Change the index value of an array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I was wondering if it was possible to change what kind of value a java array uses as its index so instead of having

```
Fruit[0] = orange
```

you could have

```
Fruit[orange] = orange
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually java only accept (non-negative) integer for its index, to achieve "string", you can use Map. This is example for use Map: [using Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943588/can-java-use-string-as-an-index-array-key-ex-arraya-1). Or if you still want to use array, you can use enumeration: [java enum tutorial](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/08/enum-in-java-example-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to [associative array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) notation in languages such as Perl. In Java they are represented by `Maps`:

```
Map<String, String> fruitMap = new HashMap<>();
fruitMap.put("orange", "orange");
```

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming that `orange` is a string or enum or some other object type ...)

> I was wondering if it was possible to change what kind of value a java array uses as its index ...

No.  It is not possible

The type of the index of a Java array is `int`.  This is "baked into" the Java language design and the JVM design at a fundamental level.  Even using `long` values as array indexes or array sizes is impossible in Java up to and including Java 8.

Just changing Java to allow `long` array indexes would be a massive task.  And I don't think it could be done without breaking lots of existing applications.  For example, there are likely to be millions of lines of deployed Java code that assume that `array.length` can be assigned to an `int`.

---

Fortunately, Java provides the equivalent of this in the form of the Map interface and its implementation classes.  The only thing that is missing is the "syntactic sugar" that would make a Map access look like regular Java array access.