# objectName["propertyName"] in JAVA

Tags: java

In javascript we can select a value from an array using a key instead of an index number, doing something like this:
`objectName["propertyName"]` or `objectName.propertyName`

There is something like this in JAVA?

Comment: What you want to use is possible a [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)?

Comment: You can use objectName[array.indexOf(4)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java don't support array with keys.

Use hashmap instead.

[Can Java use String as an index array key? (ex: array["a"]=1;)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943588/can-java-use-string-as-an-index-array-key-ex-arraya-1)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately in Java there is no straight way to do that. But you can use reflection to achieve it. For convenience purpose you could create utility methods and simulate somewhat the javascript notation.

See here [Java: How can I access a class's field by a name stored in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127197/java-how-can-i-access-a-classs-field-by-a-name-stored-in-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays do not support the use of keys. I'd recommend using a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead. Keep in mind, however, that HashMaps don't keep their order as stable as an array does, so iterating through a HashMap may not get the same order every time.